# How to parse XML attributes in Hive?

Tags: xml, hive, xml-parsing

I can parse out values like 9531 since they're enclosed in the tag `StatusValue`. But how do I do the same for `DateTime`, `FromAppId` and `MessageId`?

```
<PhoneCallEvent DateTime="2018-09-10T12:51:33.743-04:00" 
                FromAppId="200002" 
                MessageId="3407802">   
  <LoanNumber>307375</LoanNumber> 
  <StatusValue>9531</StatusValue>
  <StatusUserCommonID>2561550</StatusUserCommonID>
  <CallDirection>Inbound</CallDirection>
  <CallStartTime>2018-09-10T12:49:37.000-04:00</CallStartTime>
  <CallEndTime>2018-09-10T12:51:28.000-04:00</CallEndTime>
  <VectorDirectoryNumber/>
</PhoneCallEvent>
```

Comment: What sort of code are you using to parse? Many languages have XML/HTML parsing libraries that are far safer than doing it manually. What you're looking for is something that can query the *attributes*. Although I am not at all familiar with Hive...

Answer (score 0):

Hive has XPath functions:

`SELECT xpath (` ***xml_string*** `,` ***xpath*** `) FROM src LIMIT 1`

`SELECT xpath_string (` ***xml_string*** `,` ***xpath*** `) FROM src LIMIT 1`

`SELECT xpath_`***type***  `(` ***xml_string*** `,` ***xpath*** `) FROM src LIMIT 1`

So, for example, you might use `xpath_string` with the XPath,

```
/PhoneCallEvent/@DateTime
```

to select the `DateTime` attribute value.